# How Can I display values of database row in HTML table different column

Tags: php, html, database, html-table

i have the following table on my database: student, mark, out_of ,subject, subject_routing, grade, and student_grade.
among these table, table student, mark, and out_of are where i face the problem.
the structure of those three table are as follow.
[[Mark of students table[out_of table(for mark)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEwRo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATT8m.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYHUC.png)

from the above three table i want to display a table called "result" on HTML table which i need it looks like this.
[Result table that i want to display on html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KAJi.png)
the code i am trying is the following one. but it's not working rather it display repeated row values.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "jion";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title> test table of data</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan ="2">S/N</th>
            <th rowspan ="2">ID</th> 
            <th rowspan ="2">Full Name</th>
            <th colspan = "3">Student Mark(Mathematics Subject)</th>
            <th>Sum</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
    $sql="select DISTINCT student_name.index_number as id,
                                   student_name.fname as First_name,
                                   student_name.lname as last_name,
                                   out_of.out_of as out_of,
                                   mark.mark as mark
                                   from student_name 
                               
                    INNER JOIN mark ON mark.st_id = student_name.index_number
                    INNER JOIN out_of ON out_of.subject_id = mark.subject_id 
                    WHERE mark.subject_id=1";
                    
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$count = 0;
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){    
    $count++;
    $sum = $row['mark']++;
    $sum_out = $row['out_of']++;
                    ?>
        <tr>
             <td><?php echo $row['out_of']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['out_of']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['out_of']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $sum_out; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['First_name']; ?> <?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['mark']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['mark']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['mark']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sum; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php  } }   ?>
       
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: instead of posting images post code directly

Comment: Please read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

For the other images (text would be better here as well) please see [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question)

Comment: In your code there are parts missing. You have a `$sql` variable which is not used and we can't see where and how `$row` is defined.

Comment: I have edited my post. Please see it again.